# Need assistance for multithreading application using QThread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, sockets

I am quite new to QThread and I want to make a multithreading application with Qt. There are lots of online sources, some recommend subclassing QThread, some say that it is not true, and they use moveToThread function. I am really confused. Maybe it depends on requirements, so I am writing my requirements.

The software will communicate with a device over UDP protocol. The device sends received packet back to sender as an ACK. Since UDP is not reliable, I want to add a bit reliabilty to communication by checking the answer from device. I want to give a little bit time to device to send answer, If the answer (ACK packet) does not come, I want to send the same packet again. If a wrong answer packet comes, (out of sequence packets), I can ignore it, no need to resequence them. There will be some packets (commands for device), that will be send periodically, for example each second.

I want to make all communication in a thread using QThread. The thread will be started by clicking a button and communication will start (some packets will be sent periodically). The communication will stop by clicking a button.

So how can I do that? I need only steps.

**EDIT:**

I have already impelemented a blocking read and write. I am moving it to a Thread using moveToThread function and starting the thread. But I don't know whether it is the best way for my use-case.

I send some datagrams one after the other as following, for example:

```
int UDP::readCalibration(..)
{
    while(readStatus() != 0);

    // Send addr, read page command and read buffer command
    // one after each
    writeRegisterBlock(LOW_ADDR, CalibAddr, 2); // Blocking
    writeRegister(CMD_Reg, READ_PAGE);          // Blocking
    readRegisterBlock(READ_BUF, data, 128);     // Blocking
}
....
int UDP::writeRegisterBlock(...) 
{
   ....// Build UdpPacket
   return UDP_Send(UdpPacket, &ReceivePacket);
}
int UDP::writeRegister(...) 
{
   ....// Build UdpPacket
   return UDP_Send(UdpPacket, &ReceivePacket);
}
int UDP::readRegisterBlock(...) 
{
   ....// Build UdpPacket
   return UDP_Send(UdpPacket, &ReceivePacket);
}
// and UDP_Send function, this is the important part
int UDP::UDP_Send(QByteArray UdpPacket, QByteArray *ReceivePacket)
{
    QByteArray Datagram;
    QHostAddress SenderAddress;
    quint16 SenderPort;
    int UDP_RetVal = -1, timeOutCounter = -1, NrOfSend = -1, NrOfRecv = -1, retVal = -1;
   bool pendingDatagram = false;

   SetContinueToRecv(true); // sets a boolean variable with mutex
   SetContinueToSend(true); // sets a boolean variable with mutex

   while ((NrOfSend < MAX_RETRY) && GetContinueToSend())
   {
       NrOfSend++;
       SetContinueToRecv(true); // start receiver loop
       UDP_RetVal = udpSocket->writeDatagram(UdpPacket, DestinationIP, port);

       if(UDP_RetVal < 0)
       {
           qDebug() << "udpSocket error";
       }
       else
       {
           while((NrOfRecv <  MAX_RETRY) && GetContinueToRecv())
           {
               pendingDatagram = false;

               while (!pendingDatagram && (timeOutCounter < TIMEOUT_MS))
               {
                   msleep(SLEEP_MS);
                   timeOutCounter++;
                   pendingDatagram = udpSocket->hasPendingDatagrams();
               }

               if (timeOutCounter < TIMEOUT_MS)
               {
                   Datagram.resize(udpSocket->pendingDatagramSize());
                   udpSocket->readDatagram(Datagram.data(), Datagram.size(), &SenderAddress, &SenderPort);

                   //Compare only first 4 bytes, cmd, nr, addr
                   if((UdpPacket.mid(0, 4) == Datagram.mid(0, 4)) && (SenderAddress == DestinationIP) )
                   {
                       retVal = 0;
                       //Take only data , not commands
                       ReceivePacket->resize(Datagram.size()-4);
                       ReceivePacket->replace(0, Datagram.size()-4, Datagram.right(Datagram.size()-4));
                       SetContinueToRecv(false); // Break receiver while loop
                       SetContinueToSend(false); // Break sender while loop
                   }
                   else // Wrong packet
                   {
                       SetContinueToRecv(true); // try again to receive
                       timeOutCounter = -1;
                       qDebug() << "Wrong Packet.";
                   }    // Wrong packet
               }
               else // Timeout
               {
                   qDebug() << "Timeout maximum. NrOfSend: " << NrOfSend << " NrOfRecv: " << NrOfRecv;
                   timeOutCounter = -1;
                   SetContinueToSend(true); // try again to send
                   SetContinueToRecv(false);
               }   // Timeout
           }  // Receive loop
           NrOfRecv = -1;
       }  // Succesfully sent
   }  // Send loop
   if(NrOfSend == MAX_RETRY)
   {
      retVal = -1; // Could not send.
      qDebug() << "Could not send";
   }
   return retVal;
}
```

How can I replace the blocking functions with readyRead and Timeout functions? Maybe I have to save sent datagram and in timeout I have to compare the received datagram with sent datagram, if it is same, the packet is sent and received correctly. If not, I have to send it again?

Comment: Subclassing `QObject` and using `moveToThread` is generally the way to go. I think it is pretty well explained in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#details). Did you check that out yet?

Comment: I had a brief read through the arguments about how to use QThread and like you I came to the conclusion that it was all confusing and I stopped reading. Sub classing QThread and re-implementing the run() function makes the most sense to me. Treat the run() implementation like a main() for the new thread. Create objects in it (on the stack) as you would in main(). The thing to remember is that objects created in main() belong to the main thread and objects created in run() belong to that thread. I've never had to use the moveToThread() function. thuga and I see it differently it seems :-(

Comment: If you want to have a reentrant class that runs on a different thread, then using `moveToThread` is much simpler than subclassing `QThread` to me. This allows you to use slots so you won't have to worry about mutex locking and what not when sending messages across threads.

Comment: Also worth noting is that `QUdpSocket` is asynchronous. So you can use the [`readyRead`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#readyRead) signal to get notified when there is something to be read. This means you might not even need to run it in another thread.

Comment: I suggest you to read this https://mayaposch.wordpress.com/2011/11/01/how-to-really-truly-use-qthreads-the-full-explanation/. This helped me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly advise you to use the asynchronous API that [`QUdpSocket`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qudpsocket.html) class provides for your use case.

Use a slot connected to the `readyRead()` signal, and use `readDatagram()` within that slot to actually read the received data from socket. In order to send data, use `writeDatagram()` anywhere you like, it does not block the calling thread.

You can read [Broadcast Receiver Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-broadcastreceiver-example.html) and [Broadcast Sender Example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-broadcastsender-example.html), and write similar code.

As for the timeout thing, you can have a [`QTimer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html) with its `timeout()` signal connected to the slot that sends the datagram, so that it sends it keeps sending the packet when no response comes in the specified time, and have the timer's `start()` method called in the slot connected to `readyRead()` signal (so that the timer restarts every time a datagram is received).

To answer your question about multi-threading, a usual way to use it in brief is to have a class that derives from `QObject`, and implement slots that need to be executed in that class, then instantiate a new `QThread` and call `moveToThread()` on that object to the new `QThread`. Afterwards when any of the signals connected to this object's slots is emitted the slots code gets executed in the new Thread.

However, it is worth noting that there are many ways to utilize multi-threading in Qt, and each use case has its way to implement it, have a look here [Multithreading Technologies in Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-technologies.html#example-use-cases). And In your use case, do NOT use multi-threading at all.

**EDIT:**
so you weren't able to go online, and you implemented your *blocking read and write*. . .

> I am moving it to a Thread using moveToThread function and starting the thread

first of all, you have to make sure that after you moved that `QObject` to the new thread, you don't call your function that uses blocking IO directly, instead invoke it either by connecting a signal to it and emitting that signal, or by using `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`. Because calling it directly will execute your function in the caller's thread which is most likely the GUI thread, and that's the thing we don't want to do. . .

I can see that you are calling `msleep` in your `UDP::UDP_Send`. Please don't tell me that your `UDP` class inherits from `QThread`, read my answer again to know what you should derive from.

it seems like you are polling the `QUdpSocket` by calling its `hasPendingDatagrams` every `SLEEP_MS`. if you are to continue with the blocking mode, use instead `waitForReadyRead` that way the thread will keep blocking until the moment `QUdpSocket` receives a datagram. . .

these are signs that you are not getting your code to execute in the new Thread right. . .

P.S. : re-writing your code using the asynchronous way I first told you about, is far easier, simpler and cleaner than fixing your current code.  Just read the examples I linked and feel free to ask about them if you don't understand something. . .

Comment: I couln't go online for a couple of days. Now I editted my question according to your recommendation.

Comment: Thank you very  much. No,  UDP class does not inherit from QThread, I am only moving it in a QThread usin moveToThread. I will follow your suggestions.